# Pear PHP Mailer Emails Sender and Recipient

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear, sender

I'm using Pear PHP Mailer to send an email through SMTP to a number of recipients, but for each one, it sends an additional email to the sender's email address as well.

This is my code: Any help is appreciated.

```
...

$from = "$from_email_name <$from_email_addr>";
$html_body = "$html";

$crlf = "\r\n";

$hdrs = array(
            'From'    => $from,
            'Subject' => $subject
            );
$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));

$mime->setTXTBody($text_body);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html_body);

$body = $mime->get();
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

$mail = Mail::factory('mail',
            array ('host' => $host,
                'port' => $port,
                'auth' => true,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password));

$mail->send($to_email_addr, $hdrs, $body);

....
```

Also, on the email it is sending to my sender address, its saying the correct recipient name and sender information, but its like the sender is getting a copy of each one it sends out.

Comment: Try this:
$hdrs = array('From'    => $from, 'Subject' => $subject,'To' => $to_email_addr);

Comment: @dikirill Tried it but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a "service" of your mail server provider to automatically put mails sent via the SMTP server in your IMAP/POP mail box. Ask him if that's the case.